# ChartJS doughnut colors not showing from a Flask app. All gray

Tags: javascript, flask, chart.js

Looking for some help here. The doughnut chart is rendering properly, but all the colors are gray. I've scoured the chartjs site and googled, but I can't seem to solve this.

Here's my code:

```
@app.route('/doughnut_chart')
def doughnut_chart():
    values = []
    labels =['good', 'mediocre','bad']

    colors = ['rgba(0, 153, 0, 0.1)', 'rgba(0,153,153,0.1)','rgba(102,153,51,0.1)']

    good_high = db.session.query(func.sum(Jf_Q1.highwellbeing)/func.sum(Jf_Q1.good_job)).\
        filter(Jf_Q1.working==1).filter(Jf_Q1.good_job==1)

    good_mod = db.session.query(func.sum(Jf_Q1.moderatewellbeing)/func.sum(Jf_Q1.good_job)).\
        filter(Jf_Q1.working==1).filter(Jf_Q1.good_job==1)

    good_low = db.session.query(func.sum(Jf_Q1.lowwellbeing)/func.sum(Jf_Q1.good_job)).\
        filter(Jf_Q1.working==1).filter(Jf_Q1.good_job==1)

    values = [0.82483097725875845114*100,0.14935464044253226798*100,0.01966810079901659496*100]

    return render_template('results.html', values=values,labels=labels, colors=colors)
```

and my script code on the web page:

```
    new Chart(document.getElementById("doughnut-chart"), {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels : {{labels | safe}},
                backgroundColor: {{colors | safe}},
                datasets:
                    [{ data : {{values | safe}}
                }]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Doughnut Chart Title'
                }
            }
    });
```

Here's how it looks in Chrome's inspector:

```
    new Chart(document.getElementById("doughnut-chart"), {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels : ['good', 'mediocre', 'bad'],
                backgroundColor: ['rgba(0, 153, 0, 0.1)', 'rgba(0,153,153,0.1)', 'rgba(102,153,51,0.1)'],
                datasets:
                    [{ data : [82.48309772587584, 14.935464044253226, 1.9668100799016592]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Doughnut Chart Title'
                }
            }
    });
```

I've tried hex colors such as:

```
backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9"]
```

But still no dice

This is what is looks like in Chrome and in FF:

[my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYiIB.png)

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!. datasets is a list of objects. I needed to place the backgroundColor option inside datasets as such:

```
datasets:
                    [{ data : [82.48309772587584, 14.935464044253226, 1.9668100799016592],
                    backgroundColor: ['rgba(0, 153, 0, 0.1)', 'rgba(0,153,153,0.1)', 'rgba(102,153,51,0.1)'],
                    fill: true
                }],
```

I had it outside. RTFM! lol